# How to Remove Single Quotes from String?

Tags: apex, string

I have a String like `Status = 'Submit'`, and I want to remove the single quote characters (`'`).
So my desired output is `Status=Submit`.

Comment: This is a colon `:`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily do this using the **remove**

```
status = status.remove('\'');
```

Or you can also use **removeStart, removeEnd**

```
String s = '\'Submit\'';
system.debug('--->'+s.removeEnd('\'').removeStart('\''));
```